# VS2013 C# variables appear to go out of scope after multiple await statements

Tags: c#, debugging, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on and attempting to debug a C# unit test which performs multiple `await`s to setup some database state. Variables declared and assigned early on are initially visible, but as I progress through the method, whether by stepping or continuing to a later breakpoint, those variables go *"out of scope"*.

I quote *"out of scope"* there because:

- they are most definitely still in scope
- they are still accessible to code

However, the debugger can no longer see them (*"The name 'someVariable' does not exist in the current context"*). The code follows this pattern:

```cs
await SomeAsyncCleanupMethod()
var someVar = 123;

var testData1 = SomeFactoryMethod()
var modifiedData1 = await ProcessData(testData1)
await SaveData(modifiedData1)

var testData2 = SomeFactoryMethod()
var modifiedData2 = await ProcessData(testData2)
await SaveData(modifiedData2)

var testData3 = SomeFactoryMethod()
var modifiedData3 = await ProcessData(testData3)

// Up to this point, all declared variables are inspectable, either
// by a watch, or by hovering the mouse pointer

await SaveData(modifiedData3)

// From here on, no declared variables are inspectable
// ("The name 'someVar' does not exist in the current context")
```

Things I have tried to address this:

- clean build
- restart VS
- restart PC
- reset VS settings
- empty debugger symbol cache
- import VS settings from another machine which does not exhibit the problem
- `git clean -xfd` to remove any temporary VS state?

Simple values are affected the same way as the results returned by the `await` statements. It seems to be simply a case of if too many `await`s have been called, all variables become inaccessible to the debugger.

It seems unlikely that I have got this far without using the debugger in this context, so I'd like to say this used to work. I haven't knowingly changed anything other than code, so I can offer no explanation as to why it would have stopped working.

**Update:**

I'm now doubting it's actually `await` that's to blame. After refactoring to eliminate some repetition, the statement that makes the debugger lose visibility is now a simple collection initialiser. No `await` involved.

**Update 2:**

I neglected to mention, but I was originally using code contracts. Switching them off makes the problem go away.

**Update 3:**

I've tried to reproduce this in a small, self-contained project, but have so far failed to emulate whatever complexity was triggering the misbehaviour.

Comment: "It seems unlikely that I have got this far without using the debugger in this context" - you may have used the debugger but not needed to access a local variable declared before an await, after that await. I can easily see how this could happen, in light of how async methods are transformed.

Comment: One thing to check is that you're building the debug build and that it's definitely got optimization turned off. Async/await can change pretty significantly between with optimization. Also, I'd compare the compiler version between the working machine and the broken machine.

Comment: It is a debug build and optimisation is off. The machines do differ (a 2013 Pro works, 2013 Premium does not)

Comment: But check the exact compiler version. From a developer command prompt, run csc on both machines.

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking into the generated IL too...

Comment: 12.0.21005.1 for the working case, 12.0.40629.0 for the problematic one.

Comment: You might want to come up with a minimal example of code contracts breaking the await and submit that to Connect.